# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when reading file data into 2d array

Tags: c++, ios, c, xcode, exc-bad-access

I am trying to load filedata into a 2d array, but when calling fread I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

This is how I am attempting to read my file:

```
char data[21][23];
FILE* file = fopen("1.txt", "r");
fread(data, 1, sizeof(data), file); // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Comment: Can't tell what's wrong here except one little thing... You should probably use "rb", not just "r". Hold on, is `file==NULL`?

Comment: Replaced r with rb, did not seem to have any effect on the problem. file is not NULL.

Comment: By any chance is data declared as `const`? Or, it's a local variable and you have exhausted the stack due to too many nested function calls and/or other local variables (large arrays/structs)?

Comment: data is defined as you see it in the example I provided

Comment: It might be iOS causing this, after some testing I found out it can't find the proper file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, 2-dimensional arrays (nxm) are represented as a array of n pointers to n arrays of size m.

fread will read into the memory region pointed at by the given pointer.

In your case, fread will write data to the location where the n pointers are supposed to be stored. You can not simply use fread() or any similar method on 2-dimensional arrays in C.

Instead, first read into a 1-dimensional array of size m*n, then copy pointers to the 'beginnings of the lines' into an array of pointers:

```
char tmp[21*23];
FILE* file = fopen("1.txt", "r");
fread(tmp, 1, sizeof(tmp), file);
char* data[21];
int i;
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(data)/sizeof(char*); i++) {
    data[i] = &tmp[23*i];
}
```

**Update**: The sample code contained an error (I used sizeof(data), which, on 64-bit systems, will return 8 times the desired value, leading to an other EXC_BAD_ACCESS ;))

Comment: Still getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at fread. After doing some more research I found out it does only happen on ios, like I speculated earlier.

Comment: This answer is just as good as the one that was deleted. Whether the buffer is a one-dimensional array or two-dimensional array is completely irrelevant.